# java runs the batch file. - cant insert command

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, processbuilder

I am creating a Process in java which opens my batch file and runs perfectly fine.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start c:\\blah\\example.bat");
OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();
```

How do I insert a command in this example.bat file for example
inserting "cd.." through java??

Comment: Tips:  Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the batch file from Java with a `FileWriter`, prior to executing it.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime()
  .exec("cmd.exe /C START c:\\blah\\example.bat && ECHO %ERRORLEVEL% && CD ..");
OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();
```

Are you sure you want to use "START" rather than "CALL" in this context?  In a case where you have multiple commands going in a certain order,  you may benefit from "CALL" because it blocks until finished and returns an exit code.